# How to disable one button among two buttons by selecting the table row in angular js?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have two buttons: Activated and paused.
I want one of button to be disabled when I select the row of table.

IN HTML:

```
<div class="pull-right">
  <button ng-disabled ="orders.status == pause" id = "activated" class="pull-left btn btn-primary">Activated</button>
  <button ng-disabled ="orders.status == activated" id = "paused" class="pull-left btn btn-primary">Paused</button>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<table class="table table-color table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Rotation Order
      </th>
      <th>
        Tag Name
      </th>
      <th>
        Status
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>


<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="orders in  vm.rotationTable" ng-class="{selected : orders.rotationOrder == vm.idSelectedOrder}" ng-click="vm.setSelected(orders.rotationOrder)">
      <td>{{orders.rotationOrder}}</td>
      <td>{{orders.tagName}}</td>
      <td>{{orders.status}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In JScript:

```
// Code goes here

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
  myApp.controller('tagController', ['$scope',function ($scope) {

  var vm = this;
  vm.rotationTable = [
      {
          "rotationOrder": "1",
          "tagName": "Tag D",
          "status":"Activated"
      },
      {
          "rotationOrder": "2",
          "tagName": "Tag E",
          "status": "Paused"
      },
      {
          "rotationOrder": "3",
          "tagName": "Tag F",
          "status": "Activated"
      }
  ]

  vm.idSelectedOrder = null;
  vm.setSelected = function (index) {
      vm.idSelectedOrder = index;
      console.log(vm.idSelectedOrder);
  };
 }]);
```

you can see my work here.

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/UiMhLbzhxg3I5cGuiK0J?p=preview
```

and also If anyone can suggest:- How to fix hover of table row when its already selected?I do not want hover effect on row when it is already selected.

Comment: Your buttons don't have any code to actually run anything. Did you forget `ng-click`?

Comment: I fixed the question sorry about that...You can refer to plunker also.

Comment: `vm.rotationTable` only becomes `orders` inside the `ng-repeat`. Your buttons are outside of it. `orders` does not exist in their scope.

Comment: yes that is out of scope.I want then to be sync with buttons.If status is activated then activated button should be disable and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `ng-click` to

```
ng-click="vm.setSelected(orders)"
```

And instead of storing `vm.idSelectedOrder`, store the actual order. Create a `vm.selectedOrder` variable for the controller.

And in your button you'll use:

```
ng-disabled ="vm.selectedOrder.status == 'Paused'"
```

This is the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yrc7g6wSf49vI0zTtkGQ?p=preview).

Comment: Just a heads up, I did that too in the plunkr... this does appear to work, but `vm.idSelectedOrder` isn't actually a zero-based index. It's a forcefully assigned value that starts at 1. This means that clicking the last element refers to an out-of-bound index (3, where max index in a length 3 array is 2).

Comment: your logic is correct.But logic is not working on third row of table.

Comment: Changed the entire answer. Check it out.

Comment: Did you check out the plunk ? Instead of storing the id of the selected order, store the entire object. Doing this will easen your work because you will always know what is the selected order, not only it's id.

Comment: I didnot checked plunker before comment.....But I fixed exactly what you did in plunker.Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you just suggest me how can I fix that hover issue on selected row?

Comment: Change your selected class css to: background-color:#DEEBF9 !important;